# Routing optional parameters in Adonisjs

Tags: node.js, parameters, routes, postman, adonis.js

I have a problem when try to make routing with optional parameters in adonisjs. When i write different endpoint the result of parameter also different

This is my router's code:

```
Route.post('product/:id_product?', 'ProductController.addProduct')
```

If i send a parameter to this endpoint in postman

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product   //the result of parameter is null
or
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product/1    //the result of parameter is 1
```

that parameter can be read in `console.log`, but if i try to run this endpoint:

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product    //the result of parameter is null
or
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product?id_product=1    //the result of parameter also null
```

the result of `console.log` just **null**. So what's wrong with my route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you create a route this route path like this

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product/1
```

when you get this id_product in the controller like this

`console.log(params.id_product)`
so can get 1 or as you pass in a path using this

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product?id_product=1
```

this does not give you any parameter because id_product is a query parameter in this case if you get id_product in this path then you get like this

```
      const queryData = request.get();
      console.log(queryData.id_product)
```

so get 1 or as you pass this print

Comment: how about, if i create ```:id_product?``` in route? actually this optional routing will return ```http://localhost:3333/shoping/product?id_product=1 ``` or ```http://localhost:3333/shoping/product/1```? i confused, because i still can use both of that endpoint..

Comment: if you create this route ```:id_product?``` then you get ```params.id_product``` and you get after ```?``` query parameter then use ```request.get() ```
```http://localhost:3333/shoping/product/1``` this is your endpoint of ```:id_product```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 differences :

1. [Request body](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request)

url examples:

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product?id_product=1
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product?id_product=1&name=test
```

route example : `shoping/product`

controller integration :

```js
test ({request}) {
 const product = request.only(['id_product', 'name'])

 console.info(product.id_product) //output 1
}
```

2. [Route parameters](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/routing#_route_parameters)

url example :

```
http://localhost:3333/shoping/product/1
```

route example : `shoping/product/:id_product?`

controller integration :

```js
test ({params}) {
 const id_product = params.id_product

 console.info(id_product ) //output 1
}
```